Extra quotes when converting Date to string for fetching request
My Date objects from and to are incorrectly encoded with extra quotes which results in bad request URL. I've tried multiple functions to convert the Date to string (toJSON, toISOString, encodeURIComponent) but nothing has worked so far. For the fetching itself I am using Nuxt's fetching API which is a wrapper around ofetch:
  const fromISO = encodeURIComponent(from.toISOString())
  const toISO = encodeURIComponent(to.toISOString())
  const { data, error } = await useAPI<RateResponse>(`/users/${userId}/projects/${projectId}/rates`, {
    query: { from: fromISO, to: toISO }
  })

This is the successful URL I get from swagger:
https://example.com/users/4/projects/17/rates?from=2024-10-24T16%3A45%3A00.000Z&to=2024-10-24T17%3A45%3A00.000Z

and this is the one from the app:
https://example.com/users/4/projects/17/rates?from=%222024-10-24T16:45:00.000Z%22&to=%222024-10-24T17:00:00.000Z%22

Here is the useApi.ts
import type { UseFetchOptions } from 'nuxt/app'

export function useAPI<T>(url: string | (() => string),options?:UseFetchOptions<T>) {
  return useFetch(url, {
    ...options,
    $fetch: useNuxtApp().$api
  })
}

and here the $api
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  const loginStore = useLoginStore()

  const api = $fetch.create({
    baseURL: useRuntimeConfig().public.apiUrl,
    retryStatusCodes: [401],
    retry: 1,
    retryDelay: 500,
    onRequest({ request, options, error }) {
      if (loginStore?.token) {
        const headers = options.headers || {}
        if (Array.isArray(headers)) {
          headers.push(['Authorization', `Bearer ${loginStore.token}`])
        } else if (headers instanceof Headers) {
          headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${loginStore.token}`)
        }
        console.log(request)
      }
    },
    async onResponseError({ request, options, response }) {
      console.log(options)
      console.log(response)
      if (response.status === 401) {
        if (loginStore.refreshToken) {
          try {
            await loginStore.refreshExpiredToken()
          } catch {
            loginStore.logout()
            await nuxtApp.runWithContext(() => navigateTo('/login'))
          }
        }
        loginStore.logout()
        await nuxtApp.runWithContext(() => navigateTo('/login'))
      }
    }
  })

  // Expose to useNuxtApp().$api
  return {
    provide: {
      api
    }
  }
})

And here is the error I get back from API which shows the extra quotation marks:


Show us the implementation of useAPI…

Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. I see no possibility for this to happen with the code provided. You don't need encodeURIComponent, but it cannot affect the way it works. Considering that from is date object, from.toISOString() cannot produce quotes, and no extra quotes can be added by $fetch too, unless custom serializer is used or something else, but nothing in the code above suggests that

@EstusFlask It is actually happening even when I use just $fetch instead of useAPI (or useFetch) adding from and to plain Date objects into the query parameter without any manipulation. I've tried a different machine just in case and the result is the same

@zmaten from.toISOString() is evaluated to regular string, and strings aren't wrapped with quotes in query parameters, unless toISOString was overriden in some awkward way, etc. You could make it simpler by passing "foo" and "bar" strings instead. What you describe is not typical behaviour of $fetch and not possible under normal circumstances.  A way to reproduce is necessary. Currently only you are able to debug this. This should be possible without an actual backend, a failed request will be visible in logs. Try to reduce the project to the size of "hello world" and create a repo for it

More of a workaround than a proper solution to my problem, but when I use the parameters in the URL directly instead of in the query argument it works as expected:
  const fromISO = from.toISOString()
  const toISO = to.toISOString()    

  const { data, error } = await useAPI<RateResponse>(
    `/users/${userId}/projects/${projectId}/rates?from=${fromISO}&to=${toISO}`)


If you’re getting extra quotes around your Date objects in the URL, it could be because ofetch is adding its own encoding. Here’s a quick fix:

Skip encodeURIComponent: Since ofetch already handles query parameters, you can just pass toISOString() directly.
Use query in the API call: Let ofetch handle all the encoding for you.

Try this:
const fromISO = from.toISOString();
const toISO = to.toISOString(); 
const { data, error } = await useAPI<RateResponse(`/users/${userId}/projects/${projectId}/rates`, { query: { from: fromISO, to: toISO } }); `


Unfortunately this is one of the original versions I've unsuccessfully tried. Even without it I get the extra quotes around the from and to values
